# URW-Garamond with mathdesign is typesetting vertical double-quote as vertical double-quote

Tags: mathdesign

I just started using URW-Garamond with mathdesign, and it's typesetting straight double-quote character as a straight double-quote rather than a right double-quote.  How can I fix this?

That is, when I put this in my header:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
```

I get a nice Garamond in my output, but `"` in my input file produces a Garamond version of the same character in the output.  If I use two single-quotes instead, it comes out properly as a double right-quote.  I could switch to typing `''` or set up a macro, but this is undesirable for more than one reason.

Is there any way to use urw-garamond without this non-traditional behavior for `"`?

Answer (score 5):

The T1 encoding is set up so that the fonts have a straight double quote in the position of the `"` character.

One should never use `"` for typesetting closing quotes in TeX anyway. The correct way is `''`.

The package `csquote` can be considered, since it avoids marking quotes explicitly.

Comment: What about changing the catcode of " to active and defining it to mean closing double quote? Is this a bad idea?

Comment: egreg, I tend toward the "it's worked for years, so don't break it" philosophy.  A minority view these days.  Ian, I assume you mean editing the encoding?  I may figure out how to do that ... eventually.  For now I need to get some work done!  In CM, apparently. :-)  Thanks!

Comment: I've posted my suggestion with more detail as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @egreg says, it's probably best to switch to using two single quote marks.  However, a dirty hack is to make `"` active so that it acts as a single character control sequence. Here I have defined it to produce `++`, to avoid any visual confusion between the different types of quote mark.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\catcode`\"=\active 
\def"{++} 
\begin{document}
"abc"def 
\end{document}
```

Inside the braces you would need two single right quotes instead of `++`.

Comment: This will have catastrophic consequences as soon as one loads `babel` with languages where `"` is a shortcut.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The log files for my documents list a huge number of hyphenation patterns, but I am not encountering any problems when I add the catcode change and definition to the preamble.

Comment: Try your code adding the line `\usepackage[german]{babel}` to the preamble.

Comment: Ah, now I see it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  I will switch to using two single quotes, but will figure out how to configure my editor to do it automatically when I get a chance.  Ian's suggestion looks like a good temporary solution until then, since I won't be using Babel in the immediate future.

Comment: Learned the hard way that a disadvantage of '' is that LaTeX thinks ''' means double-quote single-quote, when I meant the reverse.  So now instead of '" , I have to type '\,'' .  Sigh.  I understand that there has to be some way to typeset straight-quotes, but to my way of thinking, the ubiquity of double-right-quote makes the newer, more elegant policy (" means straight-quotes is more elegant than " means right-double-quote) a policy that is less practical--to a degree that makes it undesirable. Oh well. I'll use both methods as convenient, and try to stay out of trouble. -Rebel with a Quote