# Cannot make double quotes curly

Tags: quoting

I'm required to use a complex LaTeX template, and for some reason it's making all my double quotes appear straight. Single quotes (both ` and ') appear in the normal, curly way. Here are all the packages that this template is using. Any idea which one might be causing my straight quote problems? (Sorry, I know it's a lot!) I imagine I could replace all my double quotes with two single quotes, but I'm importing a lot of content from other documents, so that would be a bit pain.

```
\usepackage{booktabs}  % professionally typeset tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{verbatim}% multiline commenting
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{abbrevs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{units} 
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
```

(Yes, I know, this is the opposite problem that most people have with double quotes, and it's making it very difficult to find an answer to this question by searching.)

Comment: you have all those lines but the example isn't actually an example of the question. Please edit the example so that it has `\`\`foo''` and produces an unexpected output. Preferably then you could remove all packages that you can remove while still showing the problem, to help people debug for you.

Comment: Off-topic: Since your preamble contains the instruction `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}`, the later `\usepackage{colortbl}` directive does nothing at all (and should probably be omitted to reduce code clutter).

Comment: You really need to tell us which document class you employ and which LaTeX format -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or something else -- you employ to typeset the document. And, do yourself a favor and don't try to load packages more than once (e.g., the `array` package).

Comment: Let me guess: You're using a template from a shady web site, right?

Comment: Well, after taking @DavidCarlisle's advice I was able to narrow it down to the mathdesign package (of course the very last one). See [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42626/urw-garamond-with-mathdesign-is-typesetting-vertical-double-quote-as-vertical-do)

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Yes, it's the thesis template at that shady University I attend :)

Comment: so this is a duplicate? and the main issue was the input was wrong and had `"` not `''` ?